# Suggesting to file a bug report as an answer

Tags: discussion, debugging-questions

Sometimes the situation described in a question on SO is basically due to some bug in the underlying user's third party software stack.

In those cases, is it good practice to suggest to the OP in an answer to the question to just file a bug report to the culprit software project or should this only be remarked in a comment to the question?

In the latter case, I would say it becomes more appropriate to post a full answer stating that this is a *known* bug in software X and here is a link to the bug report in the associated bug-tracker.

Comment: An answer that only recommends filing a bug report sounds more like a comment to me.  Demonstrating that the behaviour worked in version X but not in version Y, or isolating the circumstances in which the buggy behaviour occurs might be more like answer.

Comment: Linking to an existing bug report is a valid answer (though also explaining why it's a bug is preferable). Simply suggesting that the OP should file a bug report isn't a valid answer though.

Comment: I would also suggest quoting and citing the relevant information, from a confirmation that the bug does exist, is also important.  The confirmation would have to be from a maintainer, a confirmation from other users, typically isn't very reliable.

Comment: Some other SE sites close such questions as off-topic because the community cannot really give a useful answer besides "it's a bug". Maybe on SO that would also be a suitable approach, especially for bugs that don't have easy workarounds/alternatives.

Comment: @cigien: Do you differentiate between confirmed bugs and bug reports? Personally, I usually consider them _NAA_ if it’s “There’s a big report [link]” but valid if it’s “This is a known bug [link]”. The former doesn’t really confirm anything outside of the fact that someone else had the same problem and _believes_ it is a bug. The latter is a claim backed up by an _authoritative citation_.

Comment: @Marijn I feel like "it's a bug" *is* a useful answer in many cases. To strip it down to the essentials a Q is saying "I'm trying to do X and it doesn't work" and the answer is "No, X does not work". Due to a bug, sure, but that's still useful to know, rather than chasing a non-existent solution.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Yeah, it's definitely preferable if the bug report is confirmed, but even if the answer links to an existing bug report, I don't feel it's NAA. At least, I don't personally flag those answers as NAA, but some mods might accept such a flag if raised, and delete the answer anyway.